# How to add css class to Captcha

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

In my register form I have customized the text boxes using css class. I am not sure how to add my css class to Captcha.

Here is my text box code to enter captcha code. how do I add my css class to this?

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <label class="medialabel required" for="Captcha">Please enter the code</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        @{ var exampleCaptcha = new MvcCaptcha("Captcha"); }
                        @Html.Captcha(exampleCaptcha)
                        @Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode") 
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("CaptchaCode", null, new { @class= "myClass"})
```